# Can I speed up Insertion Sort by using a tree for finding insertion positions?

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis, sorting, search-trees, arrays

I want to implement an insertionSort-algorithm. Let's say I have these pseudocode.

```
function insertionSort(F)
  for i <- 1 to n - 1 do
    j  <- findInsertPosition(F, i, 0, i - 1)
    insert(F, i, j)
  end for
end function
```

Now I want to implement the `findInsertPosition` function. Say I give this function my list, which is an array, and change this array into a tree, so that I can search iteratively in this tree for my element.

Would my complexity for the whole code be still maintained in $O(n \log n)$?

Comment: The answer to this question completely depends on how you implement the "tree" and "insert".

Comment: Note that `findInsertPosition` operates on the already sorted part of the array!

Answer (score 1):

> Would my complexity for the whole code be still maintained in $O(n \log n)$?

Let's check where we're coming from: Insertion Sort runs in time $\Theta(n^2)$ (worst and average case) if you implement `findInsertionPosition` (`fIP`) with a simple loop that scans the array.

Second, let's check what we can possible achieve. Assume that `fIP` runs in time $O(1)$. We *still* get $\Theta(n^2)$ since `insert` alone takes times linear in `i` in each iteration (worst and average case), adding up to $\Theta(n^2)$.

Third, why use a tree? You can easily achieve running-time *logarithmic* in `i` for `fIP` (for a total of [something](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+log%282,+i%29+over+i%3D1+to+n-1) in $\Theta(n \log n)$) by using binary search. That would still be dominated by the cumulative cost of `insert`, of course.

If you *did* use a tree, it would make the most sense to not throw it away between iterations; `fIP` would be obsolete. You would effectively have sorting by creating a search tree (which we don't really call Insertion Sort) but, yes, *that* would have running-time in $\Theta(n \log n)$, provided you use a balanced search tree.

In summary, no, it does not make sense to try and tweak Insertion Sort by using search trees.